# Iterate through all agents of a type

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic

simply said I want to get the current position of a moving agent and change the rotation so the agent is facing to the camera. There are multiple agents of the same type and I'm not sure how to iterate through these agents and change the rotation for everyone.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your agent's class is Agent and your population of agents is agents:

```
  for(Agent a : agents){
       a.setRotation(angle);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I discovered another problem: When moving the view in a 3D-Window the camera position doesn't change. Is there a way to adapt the camera position or get the coordinates of the view?